# Need to lock/disable button in access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I need to disable/lock two buttons. I have a form which has a subform which in turn has another subform. Two buttons in the third subform that I need to disable/lock depending on a condition in the `OnCurrent()` of the second subform. The third subform is locked `subform3.locked=true`. Everything in the third subform gets locked (txtboxes,comboboxes) except the two buttons i have added.

I have tried to place this code right below the code where the third subform is locked:
`.subform.locked=true`

`Forms![subform2]![subform3].Form![buttonname].visible=false`

But this has not worked.
Also, in the `OnLoad` of subform3 tried to run an if condition that checks if subform3 is locked and if true make `button.visible=false`. This has not worked either.

Very new to access.
Appreciate the help.

Comment: Try the `enabled=false` instead of `locked`.

Comment: Hi vacip ...tried it already...not working .. i hope the code that i hav mentioned above is correct

Comment: Well, then you can try disabling both buttons separately...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find this site the best reference:  http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm

If your code is in the main form then:

```
Private Sub btnOnMainForm_Click()
    Me.btnToDisableOnMainForm.Enabled = False
    Me.SubForm1.Form.btnToDisableOnSubForm1.Enabled = False
    Me.SubForm1.Form.SubForm2.Form.btnToDisableOnSubForm2.Enabled = False
End Sub
```

If it's in the first subform then:

```
Private Sub btnOnSubForm1_Click()
    Me.btnToDisableOnSubForm1.Enabled = False
    Me.Parent.btnToDisableOnMainForm.Enabled = False
    Me.SubForm2.Form.btnToDisableOnSubForm2.Enabled = False
End Sub
```

If it's in the second subform then:

```
Private Sub btnOnSubForm2_Click()
    Me.Parent.Parent.btnToDisableOnMainForm.Enabled = False
    Me.Parent.btnToDisableOnSubForm1.Enabled = False
    Me.btnToDisableOnSubForm2.Enabled = False
End Sub
```

If it's not on the form then:

```
Sub LockControlsFromNormalModule()
    Forms.MainForm.btnToDisableOnMainForm.Enabled = False
    Forms.MainForm.SubForm1.Form.btnToDisableOnSubForm1.Enabled = False
    Forms.MainForm.SubForm1.Form.SubForm2.Form.btnToDisableOnSubForm2.Enabled = False
End Sub
```

To turn the enabled property on and off with the same code you can use:

```
Private Sub btnOnMainForm_Click()
    With Me
        With .btnToDisableOnMainForm
            .Enabled = Not .Enabled
        End With
        With .SubForm1.Form
            With .btnToDisableOnSubForm1
                .Enabled = Not .Enabled
            End With
            With .SubForm2.Form.btnToDisableOnSubForm2
                .Enabled = Not .Enabled
            End With
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Use the `WITH` command here is the same as writing:

```
Private Sub btnOnMainForm_Click()
    Me.btnToDisableOnMainForm.Enabled = Not Me.btnToDisableOnMainForm.Enabled
    Me.SubForm1.Form.btnToDisableOnSubForm1.Enabled = Not Me.SubForm1.Form.btnToDisableOnSubForm1.Enabled
    Me.SubForm1.Form.SubForm2.Form.btnToDisableOnSubForm2.Enabled = Not Me.SubForm1.Form.SubForm2.Form.btnToDisableOnSubForm2.Enabled
End Sub
```

**Note** - MainForm, SubForm1 and SubForm2 are the names I saved the forms as.
txtboxOnMainForm, txtboxOnSubForm1 and txtboxOnSubForm2 are the names I gave to the controls on the forms.

Comment: There is no Locked property for a button. `Enabled=False` will grey the button out and render it inoperable. Locking a subform on it's own does not lock or prevent any controls being used afaik?

Comment: I was so busy explaining how to reference the forms that I ignored the fact it was buttons and not any other kind of control.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: thank u darren...it worked ...the link u have provided was very helpful too..the code that i was using to refer to the button was wrong...thanks for rectifying it ..cheers